# not join product and custom table magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, module

```
 public function getProductFinalPrice($observer)
 {
     $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
     $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
     $collection->getSelect()->join(array('membership' => $resource->getTableName("membership/membership")), "main_table.membership_product = membership.membership_id", array('membership.discount','membership.discount_type','membership.membership_id'));
 //........
 }
```

Note: `membership_product` is

```
 $setup = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('catalog_setup');

 $setup->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'membership_product', array(
    'group'   => 'General',
    'type'   => 'int',
    'input'   => 'select',
    'label'   => 'Membership',
    'backend'   => '',
    'frontend'  => '',
    'source'   => 'membership/entity_attribute_source_membership',
    'visible'   => 1,
    'user_defined'   => 1,
    'used_for_price_rules'  => 1,
    'position'   => 2,
    'unique'   => 0,
    'default'    => '',
    'sort_order'   => 103
));
```

> Unknown column 'main_table.membership_product' in 'on clause'

Answer (score 1):

The attribute `membership_product` not exists in the current product collection select. If this attribute is exists (at all), you need to add it manually, like this:

```
 public function getProductFinalPrice($observer)
 {
     $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
     $collection->addAttributeToSelect('membership_product'); // changes
     $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
     $collection->getSelect()->join(array('membership' => $resource->getTableName("membership/membership")), "main_table.membership_product = membership.membership_id", array('membership.discount','membership.discount_type','membership.membership_id'));
 //........
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I used

> Mage::log($collection->getSelect()->__toString(), null, "xdsd.log");

mysql pasted phpmymin

> `SELECT`e`.*,`link_table`.`parent_id`,`at_color`.`value`AS`
>   color`,`at_size`.`value`AS`size`,`membership`.`discount`,`
>   membership`.`discount_type`,`membership`.`membership_id`FROM`
>   catalog_product_entity`AS`e`INNER JOIN`
>   catalog_product_super_link`AS`link_table`ON link_table.product_id
>   = e.entity_id  INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_color`ON (`at_color`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_color`.`attribute_id`= '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id`= 0) 
>   INNER JOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_size`ON
>   (`at_size`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_size`.`attribute_id`= '180') AND (`at_size`.`store_id`= 0) 
>   INNER JOIN`membership`ON main_table.membership_product =
>   membership.membership_id WHERE (link_table.parent_id = 421) AND
>   (((`e`.`required_options`!= '1') OR (`e`.`required_options` IS
>   NULL))) AND (at_color.value IS NOT NULL) AND (at_size.value IS NOT
>   NULL)

```
 Note: 1054 - Unknown column 'main_table.membership_product' in 'on clause'
```